# Add two months on start date in CRM using Javascript

Tags: javascript, crm

I have task  to make expiry date by adding two months on start date.

I have found this code:

```
    var startDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_startdate').getValue();
    var expiryDate = new Date();
    expiryDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+60); //Add 60 days

    var expiryField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_expirydate').setValue(expiryDate);
```

I can see here how to add 60 days, but I need to add exactly 2 months. Can someone help me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like following:

```
var startDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_startdate').getValue();
startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + 2);
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_expirydate').setValue(startDate);
```